# i am unable to populate my tags data which have a many to many relation in asp.net core view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, linq, asp.net-core-2.0

i have a many to many relation of QuestionSkill with UserQuestion and SkillTag, all the skill names are saved in SkillTag table and other question details are saved in UserQuestion table there foreign keys are placed in QuestionSkill from where i should get the related tags. 
[here is my database schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntfzw.png)

i am also using pagination that why i have some kind of limited ways to do it. 
here is my controller function

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
  {

            ViewData["CurrentSort"] = sortOrder;

            ViewData["NameSortParm"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
            ViewData["DateSortParm"] = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";

            ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = searchString;

            //Check User Profile is complete or not 
            var user = await _userManager.GetCurrentUser(HttpContext);
            var userPersonalRow = _context.UserPersonalDetail.Where(a => a.UserId == user.Id).SingleOrDefault();
            var questions = from q in _context.UserQuestion.OrderByDescending(x => x.UserQuestionId) select q;
            foreach (var qi in questions)
            {
                var qid = qi.UserQuestionId;
                var skillTag = _context.SkillTag.Select(g => g.SkillTagId);
                foreach (var skill in skillTag)
                {
                    var questionSkill = _context.QuestionSkill.Where(f => f.UserQuestionId.Equals(qid) && f.SkillTagId.Equals(skill)).Select(s => s.SkillTag.SkillName);
                    TempData["myData"] = questionSkill;

                }


            }
```

this is the part of my view which is not working like it should:

```
  <div class="col-xs-9">
                            <h3 class="font-size16 margin-bottom6"><a href="/Question/QuestionDetail/@question.UserQuestionId">@question.Title</a></h3>
                            <span class="widget-tags-sm">
                                @{

                                <a>   @TempData["myData"]</a>


                                }
                            </span>
                            <p class="inline small-font margintop6 float-right"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> @question.PostTime <a><i class="fa fa-user"></i></a></p>
                        </div>
```

i have tried ViewData too to send the tags but. i think my approch for getting tags is wrong i.e **getting Question id and skillId from UserQuestion table and SkillTag table respectively and then matching their id in QuestionSkill table and then getting the tags of each question.**

Comment: Why don't you use navigation properties?

Comment: i have used navigation properties but the issue is i can't send it directly to the view because of pagination. i have to send it as a chunk of data using something like ViewData or TempData but it also shows errror in the foreach loop of view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need `Question` data and tags in one line so you can use paging. I'd use a view model class to achieve that. For example `QuestionViewModel`:

```
var questions = (from q in _context.UserQuestion.OrderByDescending(x => x.UserQuestionId)
                 select new
                 {
                     q.UserQuestionId,
                     q.Title,
                     q.PostTime,
                     Tags = q.QuestionSkillSelect(s => s.SkillTag.SkillName)
                 }).AsEnumerable()
                 .Select(x => new QuestionViewModel
                 {
                     UserQuestionId = x.UserQuestionId,
                     Title = x.Title,
                     PostTime = x.PostTime,
                     Tags = string.Join(", ", x.Tags)
                 })
```

This will give you all tags comma-separated in one line. Now of course you'll have to modify the model variable in your cshtml file.

`AsEnumerable` is used to continue the query in memory, because `string.Join` isn't supported in an Entity-Framework LINQ query and I like to take control over client-side evaluation myself.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Foreach` is not a good practice to retrieve the data from db, you may use Join for such cases, please refer below the sample code for join in LINQ.

```
var Question = (from a in _context.SkillTag
                   Join b in _context.UserQuestion on a.YourRefferedColumn=b.YourRefferedColumn
                   Join c in _context.QuestionSkill on b.YourRefferedColumn=c.YourRefferedColumn
                   where a.SkillColomnn=="Your skill"  //In this put the condition
                   select new
                   {
                   c.skillColumn
                   }).First();
```

I hope it helps.